# Ignore functions in Valgrind memcheck

Tags: valgrind, suppress-warnings

Valgrinding a program that uses openldap2's libldap is a chore because of OpenSSL's use of uninitialized memory. There exists a `--ignore-fn` option, but only for the massif subcomponent of Valgrind. Is there anything similar for memcheck to exclude traces in which certain functions appear?

```
==13795== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==13795==    at 0x6A9C8CF: ??? (in /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3)
==13795==    by 0x6A9A63B: inflate (in /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3)
==13795==    by 0x68035C1: ??? (in /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==13795==    by 0x6802B9F: COMP_expand_block (in /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==13795==    by 0x64ABBCD: ssl3_do_uncompress (in /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==13795==    by 0x64ACA6F: ssl3_read_bytes (in /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==13795==    by 0x64A9F2F: ??? (in /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==13795==    by 0x56B3E61: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.4)
==13795==    by 0x5E4DB1B: ??? (in /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.4)
==13795==    by 0x5E4E96E: ber_int_sb_read (in /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.4)
==13795==    by 0x5E4B4A6: ber_get_next (in /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.4)
==13795==    by 0x568FB9E: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.4)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a suppression file and use it to suppress errors coming from certain sources: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress